# Porque puedo llamar a un metodo sin usar objetos de este aunque no sea static

Tags: java

muy buenas comunidad mi pregunta es la siguiente.
quisiera saber porque puedo llamar a un método de una **superclase** en mi subclase
sin crear un objeto de este tipo y ademas de no ser static.

es lo que pasa mas abajo, utilizo un método heredado en el constructor de la subclase pero la manera en que se llama a ese método y como funciona dentro del constructor me provoca cierta ansiedad. si alguien sabe la respuesta me ayudaría muchísimo.

gracias de antemano.

```
class ClasePrueba{

public void MetodoProbando(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 5;
    int resultado = x + y;
    System.out.println(resultado);
 }


class ClaseDos extends ClasePrueba{

 public ClaseDos(){
    MetodoProbando();
 }
}

}
```

Comment: sí estás usando un objeto: `this`, o sea la instancia corriente, o tu mismo. La sentencia es equivalente a escribir: `this.MetodoProbando();`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Me parece que no has entendido cómo funciona la herencia en POO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extends se usa para heredar de una clase.

Cuando una clase hereda de otra, es como si embebieras el codigo de la clase de la cual heredas en tu misma clase.

En tu ejemplo la `ClaseDos` hereda de la `ClasePrueba`. Eso quiere decir, que tu `ClaseDos` va a tener los mismos metodos y propiedas de la `ClasePrueba` (con algunas restricciones segun la visibilidad de los metodos y propiedades, por ejemplo los metodos privados no los vas a heredar).

En tu ejemplo, no necesitas instanciar `ClasePrueba`, ya que `ClaseDos` es una sub clase de esa clase, y por lo tanto hereda sus propiedades y metodos publicos (y protected).

Definicion de herencia: [aca](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)